# Plot year over year data with month-date on X axis

Tags: pandas, matplotlib

I have a Pandas Dataframe containing daily data for a variable for 3 years. I need plot a line chart where the X axis is 1/1 to 12/31 (month and day only, no year) and  has 3 lines, one for each year. How do I plot this in matplotlib?

```
        DateTime    price
10      2007-10-06  35756.0
11      2007-10-06  34747.0
12      2007-10-07  35748.0
13      2007-10-07  34743.0
14      2007-10-08  35740.0
... ... ...
1519    2009-10-29  29564.0
1520    2009-10-30  32035.0
1521    2009-10-30  29397.0
1522    2009-10-31  32003.0
1523    2009-10-31  29256.0
```

For the above data, I need X axis to be dates from 1/1 to 12/31 and 3 lines, one each for 2007, 2008 and 2009

Comment: Please provide a [mre] of the data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

##### 1- using month-day strings for the X-axis

You can extract the [`year`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.year.html) and month-day (with [`strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.dt.strftime.html)), then [`pivot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) and [`plot`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# create a dummy dataset
df = pd.DataFrame({'DateTime': pd.date_range('2020-01-01', '2022-12-31'),
                   'price': np.sin(np.arange(1096)/80)
                  })

# if needed, ensure we have datetime
df['DateTime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['DateTime'])

# create new columns with year and month-day
# pivot and plot
(df.assign(year=lambda d: d['DateTime'].dt.year,
           day=lambda d: d['DateTime'].dt.strftime('%m-%d')
          )
   .pivot(index='day', columns='year', values='price')
   .plot()
)
```

Output:

[image: pandas plot time series with month-day as X and year as different lines]

Variant with [`seaborn.lineplot`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.lineplot.html#seaborn.lineplot):

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.ticker as ticker

ax = sns.lineplot(data=df, x=df['DateTime'].dt.strftime('%m-%d'), y='price',
                  hue=df['DateTime'].dt.year)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(ticker.LinearLocator(10))
```

Output:

[image: seaborn plot time series with month-day as X and year as different lines]

Time series with the extracted year and month-day:

```
       DateTime     price  year    day
0    2020-01-01  0.000000  2020  01-01
1    2020-01-02  0.012500  2020  01-02
2    2020-01-03  0.024997  2020  01-03
3    2020-01-04  0.037491  2020  01-04
4    2020-01-05  0.049979  2020  01-05
...         ...       ...   ...    ...
1091 2022-12-27  0.877742  2022  12-27
1092 2022-12-28  0.883663  2022  12-28
1093 2022-12-29  0.889445  2022  12-29
1094 2022-12-30  0.895088  2022  12-30
1095 2022-12-31  0.900592  2022  12-31

[1096 rows x 4 columns]
```

##### 2- using a real datetime X-axis with a common year, then changing the formatting

Another option that could be nicer would be to set up a common leap year (e.g. 2000) for plotting to benefit from the nice `MonthLocator` ticks, then to change the format to hide the year:

```
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

ax = (df
   .assign(year=lambda d: d['DateTime'].dt.year,
           day=lambda d: d['DateTime'].add(pd.DateOffset(year=2000))
          )
   .pivot(index='day', columns='year', values='price')
   .plot()
)

# add a tick for each month
ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=1))
# change the format to the month name
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b'))
```

Output:

[image: pandas plot time series with month-day as X and year as different lines and changing the MonthLocator format]

Same logic with `seaborn`:

```
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.dates as mdates

ax = sns.lineplot(data=df, x=df['DateTime'].add(pd.DateOffset(year=2000)),
                  y='price', hue=df['DateTime'].dt.year)

ax.xaxis.set_major_locator(mdates.MonthLocator(interval=1))
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(mdates.DateFormatter('%b'))
```

Output:

[image: seaborn plot time series with month-day as X and year as different lines and changing the MonthLocator format]

*NB. you can notice for all the graphs a small break in the data between February 28th − March 1st for 2021 and 2022 since those are not leap years.*